# Site selection dropdown is hidden forever on Android app

Tags: bug, android-app

The site selection component of the app, if you open, and change to a different app without closing the selection then resume the SE app, the selection tool no longer functions and doesn't drop down anymore.

Typing will fix it, but I want to tap the button.

[image: drop down in question]

Tested in editing "Your Sites" and writing Meta Stack Exchange question.

Device: Nexus 6
OS: 5.1.1